# Graph embedding that locally minimizes total edge lengths

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, calculus-of-variations

I consider a graph $G$ (possibly infinite, but locally finite) embedded in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{E}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$ such that each local perturbation of the embedding "increases the total length".  That is, for any sufficiently small neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb{E}^2$, the total length of $G \cap U$, if not empty, is minimized subject to fixed boundary points $G \cap \partial U$.

So all edges must be straight.  If a vertex has degree 3, then it must be the Fermat point of its neighbors.  If a vertex has degree 4, the adjacent edges must form two collinear pairs.  In general, the outgoing unit vectors along the edges around a vertex must sum up to 0.  I consider such embeddings as an analogy to minimal surfaces.  Examples include, of course, infinite Steiner trees --- or finite Steiner trees if I use the point at infinity wisely.

I failed to find reasonable literature about such embeddings, hence would like to ask for references.  In particular, I wonder if such an embedding may appear as (a nice supgraph of) the graph of some quasi-crystallographic tiling.

Comment: Probably you already know this, but it seems relevant to note that the  [Tutte embedding or barycentric embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_embedding) does this except that it does not minimize the total length but the total squared length of the edges.

Comment: @TimothyBudd Yes, it's indeed very similar.  That's why I believe there must already be some studies.  I am only aware of minimal surface theorists that desingularize $\mathbb{R}\times G$ into minimal surfaces (not surprising).

Comment: As written, your definition of local minimization does not make sense. Is U supposed to be a neighborhood of G? Then the intersection of G with the boundary of U will be empty. Maybe you are using some nonstandard notion of a neighborhood?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean neighborhood of a point.

Answer (score 2):

see
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03728.pdf ,
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00483.pdf and
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07872.pdf .
Here it is called geodesic nets.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I find that the works of [Ivanov](http://www.mathnet.ru/eng/person8349) and [Tuzhilin](http://www.mathnet.ru/eng/person8428) seem to be very close to what I'm looking for.